# Inserting Nested Objects EF Core 5

Tags: insert-update, ef-core-5.0, nested-object

I have the following entities:

1. Batch
2. Samples
3. SampleContainers
4. SampleTests

A batch contains many samples. A sample contains many `SampleContainers` and many `SampleTests`.

I am trying to make a copy of batch and insert into database.

Attempt #1: get function in repository:

```
return await context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
```

Controller:

```
var coc = await repository.Get(batchId);

coc.BatchStatusId = (int)Enums.BatchStatus.InProgress;
coc.IsTemplate = false;
coc.Id = 0;
        
var b = await repository.Add(coc);
```

Here only batch object was duplicated but related samples and containers were not duplicated/inserted.

Attempt #2: I changed my `Get` function as follows:

```
public async override Task<Batch> Get(int id)
{
    return await context.Set<Batch>()
            .Include(p => p.Samples)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

This time batch was duplicated but samples and containers and tests were all updated with new batchId/FK (I wanted them all to be duplicated).

Attempt #3: following [this](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9953/duplicating-related-entities-using-entity-framework-core), I implemented as follows:

```
public async Task<int> DuplicateBatch([FromBody]int batchId)
{
        try
        {
            var coc = await repository.Get(batchId);

            coc.BatchStatusId = (int)Enums.BatchStatus.InProgress;
            coc.IsTemplate = false;
            coc.Id = 0;

            var samples = coc.Samples.ToList();
            repository.DetachEntity(coc);

            var b = await repository.Add(coc);
            
            var allSampleTests = await sampleTestRepo.GetAll();
            var allSampleContainers = await sampleContainersRepo.GetAll();

            var sampletests = from st in allSampleTests
                              join s in samples on st.SampleId equals s.Id
                              select st;
            var sampleContainers = from sc in allSampleContainers
                                   join s in samples on sc.SampleId equals s.Id
                                   select sc;

            sampleRepo.DetachEntities(samples);
            
            sampleTestRepo.DetachEntities(sampletests.ToList());
            sampleContainersRepo.DetachEntities(sampleContainers.ToList());

            foreach (var s in samples) 
            {
                s.BatchId = b.Id;

                var sample = await sampleRepo.Add(s);

                foreach (var st in sampletests)
                {
                    st.SampleId = sample.Id;
                    await sampleTestRepo.Add(st);
                }

                foreach(var sc in sampleContainers)
                {
                    sc.SampleId = sample.Id;                        
                    await sampleContainersRepo.Add(sc);
                }
            }                
            
            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
 }
```

This time I am facing the following exception as soon as I reach Detach function:

> {"The property 'Batch.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified
> or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity
> with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke
> 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new
> principal."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, most of it is self explanatory.

```
public async Task<int> DuplicateBatch([FromBody]int batchId)
    {
        try
        {
            //STEP 1: Fetch the entities
            var coc2 = await repository.Get(batchId);
            var samples = coc2.Samples.ToList();

            var allSampleTests = await sampleTestRepo.GetAll();
            var allSampleContainers = await sampleContainersRepo.GetAll();

            var sampletests = samples.SelectMany(st => st.SampleTests).ToList();
            var samplecontainers = samples.SelectMany(st => st.SampleContainers).ToList();

            //STEP 2: Detach
            var coc = repository.DetachEntity(coc2);
            var samplesDetached = sampleRepo.DetachEntities(samples);
            var sampleTestsDetached = sampleTestRepo.DetachEntities(sampletests);
            var sampleContianersDetached = sampleContainersRepo.DetachEntities(samplecontainers);

            //STEP 3: Update object
            coc2.BatchStatusId = (int)Enums.BatchStatus.InProgress;
            coc2.IsTemplate = false;
            


            var b = await repository.Add(coc);

            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```